# comparing 20 different emotions in a 5 point likert scale before and after the experiment in a questionnaire

Tags: spss, experiment-design, likert, scales

I would like to know which model I can use in Spss in order to compare 20 different emotions in a 5 point Likert scale before and after the experiment for each participants... In the end, I want to find out if their emotions changed or not after the experiment... Anyone can explain step by step?

Comment: see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Matthew_Hallowell/publication/274615843_Psychological_Antecedents_of_Risk-Taking_Behavior_in_Construction/links/553a62890cf245bdd764243a.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much Antoine! You really made up my mind!